# How to tokenize a value in a custom field formatter for views?

Tags: views

I am using an custom field formatter for a view field like this:

```
function custom_fields_field_formatter_info() {

  return array(
    // the key must be unique, so it's best to prefix with your module's name.
    'custom_fields_breadcrumbs' => array(
      'label' => t('Breadcrumbs'),
      'field types' => array('entityreference'),
    ),
  );
}

/**
* Implements hook_field_formatter_settings_form().
*/
function custom_fields_field_formatter_settings_form($field, $instance, $view_mode, $form, &$form_state) {

  $display = $instance['display'][$view_mode];
  $settings = $display['settings'];
   if ($display['type'] == 'custom_fields_breadcrumbs') {
    $form = array();
       $form['active'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Mark as active'),
      '#description' => t('You can specify a node id, which should have class "active". Yo can use replacement tokens.'),
      '#default_value' => $settings['active'],
      '#size' => 4,
      '#maxlength' => 128,
      '#required' => FALSE,
    );    
  }
    return $form;
}
function custom_fields_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {

  $element = array();
  $settings = $display['settings'];

  switch ($display['type']) {
     case 'custom_fields_breadcrumbs':
      $ids = array();
      foreach ($items as $item) {
        $ids[$item['target_id']] = $item['target_id'];
      }
      $items = array();
      // http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load_multiple/7
      $items = node_load_multiple($ids, array(), FALSE);
      foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
        $label = $item->title;
        // modeled after entityreference_field_formatter_view() in entityreference.module
        if ($display['settings']['link'] && ($uri = node_uri($item))) {
          $otpions = array();
          if (isset($settings['active']) && $delta == $settings['active']) {
            $otpions = array('attributes' => array('class' => array('active')) );
          }
          $element[$delta] = array('#markup' => l($label, $uri['path'], $otpions));
        }
        else {
          $element[$delta] = array('#markup' => check_plain($label));
        }
      }
      break;
  }
  return $element;
}
```

Everything works as expected, but I want to be able to use replacement patterns for my custom setting $settings['active']. How do I do this?

I think, I have to use the method:

```
tokenize_value()
```

from the views object. But I don't have the views object within the hook, haven't I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do this. We have the views object via the parameter "display", so we can use:

```
$display['views_view']->style_plugin->tokenize_value($settings['pager']['active'], 0)
```

to tokenize a field value.